# can I use appcenter with swift for react native project?

Tags: swift, react-native

I have used appcenter before with react native and objective C.

But now this project uses swift,

how can I import the objective C library in the swift project?

```
#import "AppCenterReactNative.h"


import AppCenterReactNative
```

Do I need a bridging header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can import the library in you bridging header file and then use it in Swift files.

You're using Swift for ReactNative project, so I'm assuming you already have a bridging header file. In case you don't, here are the [instructions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift) on how to add a bridging header file.